# What is the difference in pointing a 1-D array and 2-D array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

When I run this code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
     int a[2]={1,2};
     printf("%d \t %d",*(a+1),a[1]);
}
```

It outputs : 2 2

Next I used two dimensional array for the same problem but it is giving me errors.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
     int a[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};
     printf("%d \t %d",*(a+1),a[1][0]);
}
```

My idea here is to point the address of (a+1) and print its content.But it is giving Wrong Format error. But When I point it to *(a+1) i.e, when I use * ( *(a+1)),it is printing the content.

Why does the program doesn't print the content when pointed to (a+1)? What is the difference in pointing a 1-D array and 2-D array?

Comment: You cannot print "the content of `a + 1` with `printf` directly, since `a + 1` points to an array of two ints, and `printf` doesn't know how to print arrays. You can print each member of that array, though.

Comment: In a 1D array, both `a[i]` and `*(a+1)` (which are same) are `int`s while in a 2D array, they are `int*`s , and `%d` expects an `int`, not an `int*`.

Comment: Nothing. I think it's viewed best as "C has only 1D arrays". So-called "2D arrays" are just arrays whose elements happen to themselves be arrays. We can do this easily because the size is compile-time constant.

Comment: `*(a+1)` and `a[1]` are always the same regardless of what `a` is. You seem to forget this in between your two programs ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I run this code [...] It outputs : 2 2

This is because expressions `*(a+1)` and `a[1]` are identical: square bracket expressions in C work by adding their operands together (i.e. `a` and `1` in your case) and then dereferencing the result.

> I used two dimensional array for the same problem but it is giving me errors.

This is because `*(a+1)` is of the same type as an element of `a`. When `a` is a 1D array of `int`, its elements are `int`s. When `a` is a 2D array of `int`, its elements are 1D arrays of `int`. In your second example you are trying to pass a 1D array of `int` to `printf` with the format specifier that expects a single `int`, which causes an error.

> My idea here is to point the address of (a+1) and print its content.

Then you need to add one more level of dereference (i.e. one more asterisk) to "counter" the 1D array:

```
printf("%d \t %d",**(a+1),a[1][0]);
//                 ^
```

[demo.](http://ideone.com/u99NAK)

An expression to get `a[1][1]` is slightly more complex:

```
printf("%d \t %d",*(*(a+1)+1),a[1][1]);
```

[demo.](http://ideone.com/O7QIDt)

Comment: @CoolGuy I posted a [bug on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295086/335858) explaining what has happened, and added steps to reproduce it. Thanks again for spotting this!

Answer (score 1):

A 2D array is implemented as an array of arrays; thus, in the second case, you're trying to `printf` a pointer (`a[1]`, not `a[1][0]`). If you dereference that pointer, it will work:

```
printf("%d \t %d", **(a + 1), a[1][0]);
```